# What are the main benefits of comparing SQL schemas?

Tags: sql, compare, schema

So I'v been having a little look around the interwebs and i cant seem to find any information on the benefits of doing a schema comparison.
I'm sure there is plenty of information out there, but i thought it would be a good idea to ask on S/O.

Can you please outline the main benefits of comparing SQL schemas.

Comment: You would compare two things if you wanted to know if they are the same or how they differ.  I assume the same would be true of comparing schemas.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Cheers mate for the quick reply. I see what you mean, i was thinking that there was a greater benefit to the comparison but what you mention makes good sense.